# Cisco IOS: Show ip route output order

Tags: cisco-commands, cisco-ios-12

I am runing some BGP tests through the lab before rolling them out in production (thus, any IP addresses or AS numbers etc used here are done so in a completely fictitious manner).

Something that has always bugged me is the output on Cisco IOS of `show ip route`. What order are these routes in, it isn't numerical, 1, 2, 58 ,10! They aren't grouped by protocol , or metric either.

```
br2#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 4 subnets
B       1.1.1.1 [200/0] via 10.10.0.1, 00:20:24
B       1.1.0.1 [200/0] via 10.10.0.1, 00:20:24
B       1.1.0.2 [20/0] via 10.20.0.1, 00:15:03
B       1.1.2.1 [200/0] via 10.10.0.1, 00:20:24
     2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 4 subnets
B       2.1.2.1 [20/0] via 10.100.0.1, 07:41:53
B       2.1.3.1 [20/0] via 10.200.0.1, 07:41:53
B       2.1.1.1 [20/0] via 10.100.0.1, 07:41:53
B       2.1.4.1 [20/0] via 10.200.0.1, 07:41:53
     58.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
B       58.58.58.2/32 [200/0] via 10.65.12.2, 00:20:25
S       58.58.58.0/24 is directly connected, Null0
B       58.58.58.1/32 [200/0] via 10.65.11.2, 00:20:26
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 15 subnets, 3 masks
i L2    10.10.0.0/30 [115/10] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
C       10.0.0.2/32 is directly connected, Loopback0
i L2    10.0.1.2/32 [115/30] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
i L2    10.0.0.1/32 [115/20] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
C       10.20.0.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
i L2    10.65.11.0/30 [115/20] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
i L2    10.65.13.0/30 [115/20] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
i L2    10.65.12.0/30 [115/20] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
i L2    10.65.1.0/28 [115/20] via 10.65.0.1, FastEthernet0/0
B       10.65.12.12/32 [200/0] via 10.65.12.2, 00:20:26
B       10.65.11.11/32 [200/0] via 10.65.11.2, 00:20:26
C       10.65.0.0/28 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       10.100.0.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet2/0.100
C       10.200.0.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet2/0.200
B       10.10.200.0/30 [20/0] via 10.200.0.1, 07:41:57
     60.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
B       60.0.0.60 [200/0] via 10.65.13.2, 00:20:27
```

Even within the class-full boundaries or integer boundaries of prefix groups for example, `10.65.0.0/28` comes after `10.65.11.11/32`.

Comment: `show ip cef` shows forwarding entries in numerical order

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are in order of specificity; The most specific (longest network mask) is first, and the least specific (shortest netmask) is last. If the network is variably subnetted, then they are grouped with the least-specific of the various netmasks, and ordered most-specific-first in each of the groupings.

**update**

It seems the output of `show ip route` is in the order of the internal tree structure, rather than an explicitly ordered (in the sense of route selection order) listing.

For example, here's an old post from the Cisco forums; https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/344940 regarding IOS 12.

(If anyone can write a more authoritative answer, please leave me a comment and I'll delete my answer.)

Comment: This isn't making sense to me; The output starts with eight /32's then onto 58/8, so we have gone from /32s down to /8's. Within this 58/8 range the routes are ordered /32, /30, /32 in that order!? Coming out of 58/8 we go on to 10/8 (should this come before 58/8?), then onto 60.0.0.60/32. Within 10/8 for example, the order is (work down the above output) /30, /32, /32, /32, /30....Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: Turns out the ordering is more complicated -- or rather, less meaningful -- than I had believed. Answer edited above.